# Debugging w/ Attach to Process Starts ASP.NET Dev Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I'm developing an ASP.NET site off of my Windows XP IIS Installation, and whenever I tell visual studio to attach-to-process to the aspnet_wp.exe it starts a new instance of asp.net development server. Is there a way to make it not start asp.net development server since I don't need it to launch anything?

Comment: Can you give more information on exactly how you are achieving this (step-by-step process?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to turn that off all you have to do is change the settings on the project file (using f4 to show the property grid). There is an option that says **Always Start When Debugging**, set that to false and you should be fine.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks for this. That was really bugging me, too!

Answer (score 3):

If you right-click the web project and select Properties, there is a Web tab. On there you can select the Server to use when debugging, by default it is set to the Visual Studio Development Server. You probably want to use the **Local IIS Web Server** instead.

Comment: they are trying to attach to a running process not debug from scratch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach to the IIS worker process then you need to attach to `w3wp.exe`.

Comment: On Windows XP it's not called w3wp.exe, it's called aspnet_wp.exe