# Attaching to web server process starts asp.net development server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting the same problem as this:

[Debugging w/ Attach to Process Starts ASP.NET Dev Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425016/debugging-w-attach-to-process-starts-asp-net-dev-server)

Every time I attach to the web server, I get another asp.net development server, eventually ending up with more and more.

However I don't see the option described in my Properties page.  I have Visual Studio 2010.  All I have in the Properties is "Full Path" and "Opened URL".

**EDIT:** Note: they all have different port numbers

Comment: Are these real processes?  If you try to attach to an old one does it respond?  I have only seen this when there was a problem with the process shutting down.  Right clicking on the old icon in the tray would immediately terminate it.

Comment: When I right-click on them, they don't terminate, I have to click Shut Down on the menu, so I think they're real

Answer (score 0):

You created the application as a web site.  If you create a new project (vs. web site), you will get the Project properties page that is described in the SO question you referenced.

Comment: I want to keep it as a web site.  Is there any way to avoid these processes?

Comment: Do you have IIS running locally?

Comment: Ok, I created a web site that uses the asp.net dev web server and cannot reproduce your situation.  I debug it and it launches the dev server, I stop debugging, make some changes, and start it again and it does not start a new process.  You might try the answer that dfowler gave on the question you linked to.

Comment: Also, I'm running this on Windows 7, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @adrift, yes I am running IIS locally, but I am not hitting F5, I'm attaching to the running w3p.exe, and I'm running Windows 7 too.

Comment: @JoelFan, sorry, I wish I could help here, but when I attach to w3p.exe, it does not start a new asp.net dev server process.  Does this happen for any web site you create (running in IIS), or just this one?  Hope you figure it out, good luck.